# MAVEN :: Cannot find ArtifactResolver with hint Issue

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

We are creating a package in our project using maven.

To create a pacakge we are executing mvn -Pescrow package and mvn is pointing to 
$ echo $M2_HOME
/sv/app/10.00/maven/rel

When start packaging, we are getting below exception in build.log file. Please let us know whether we can ignore this exception.

Also the package has been created successfully.

EXCEPTION SNIPPET :

> [DEBUG] All known ContainerDescritporHandler components: [file-aggregator, plexus]
>   [DEBUG] Cannot find ArtifactResolver with hint: project-cache-aware
>   org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
>         role: org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactResolver
>     roleHint: project-cache-aware
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:257)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:233)